# HERE Map Fleet API route is being calculated wrong

Tags: here-api

I could need some help with this . I am using https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/v8/calculateroute.json to calculate tollcosts for trucks and also i need the links provided to make some calculations for truck bans for each country.
The issue i have now is that on a certain route , it routes me via wrong countries .

For eg i use this request :
[https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?apiKey=""&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&ignoreWaypointVehicleRestriction=5000;0.9;all;1800&vehicle_cost=0&driver_cost=0&currency=EUR&waypoint0=49.157706,16.601180&waypoint1=46.204081678281,21.24204969351833&tollVehicleType=3&height=400cm&vehicleWeight=17000kg&limitedWeight=39000kg&emissionType=6&tiresCount=12&trailerType=2&trailersCount=1&trailerHeight=400cm&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerNumberAxles=4&heightAbove1stAxle=95cm&length=18.5m&passengersCount=1&rollups=tollsys,country,total,none,country&commercial=0&width=245cm&fuelType=diesel&weightPerAxle=8000kg&truckVerified=1&cost_optimize](https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?apiKey=%22%22&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&ignoreWaypointVehicleRestriction=5000;0.9;all;1800&vehicle_cost=0&driver_cost=0&currency=EUR&waypoint0=49.157706,16.601180&waypoint1=46.204081678281,21.24204969351833&tollVehicleType=3&height=400cm&vehicleWeight=17000kg&limitedWeight=39000kg&emissionType=6&tiresCount=12&trailerType=2&trailersCount=1&trailerHeight=400cm&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerNumberAxles=4&heightAbove1stAxle=95cm&length=18.5m&passengersCount=1&rollups=tollsys,country,total,none,country&commercial=0&width=245cm&fuelType=diesel&weightPerAxle=8000kg&truckVerified=1&cost_optimize)

It is from Czech Republic to Romania , and it always routes me via Austria + Slovenia which is very wrong . If i use other waypoints like France - Romania it is ok ( until now ) , but with this CZ-RO it is very very wrong.

Do you guys have any idea what is did wrong ?

Also , do you know if i can somehow pass the links to Here MAPS and draw the route on the map ? Because for now i use another request for the route and this one for links + tollcosts .

Hope someone can help .

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

What's your issue here? do you want to avoid a certain area ? For avoiding a certain area they have introduced it though Routing V8 and it can be done like this - `https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apikey={your_api_key}&origin=52.528120,13.285690&destination=52.529791,13.383193&return=polyline,summary,actions,instructions&transportMode=car&routingMode=fast&avoid[areas]=bbox:52.534595,13.328262,52.513706,13.362594&lang=en-us`
It's better you check their documentation. They have recently made updates to their apis .